# query to display schedule id and date in the format of ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ and name the column as FormattedDate

Tags: sql

```
select schedule_id ,date_format(column_name, '%Y-%m-%d') as Formatted date from table_name;
```

> error: ./vpl_execution: line 84: printf: 'Y': invalid format character

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

If `COLUMN_NAME`'s datatype is `DATE` (should be, right?), then

```
select schedule_id, 
       to_char(column_name, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as formatted_date
from table_name;
```

should work. I have no idea what `DATE_FORMAT` is; some function, but - what does it do?

P.S. Ah ... the question raised as I'm watching the Oracle tag which has now been removed via the edit action. If you don't use it, well - it probably won't help.

Comment: See the P.S. I wrote a few moments ago, @Cid. BTW, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work.

```
select schedule_id,to_char(travel_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as FormattedDate from schedule order by schedule_id;
```